# Using Mat in Opencv I have an error of invalid syntax

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

Good morning everyone,

I'm a beginner of python and I'm learning OpenCV for Image post-processing.
I work using Spyder and Python 2.7 on Windows 7 x64. 
I downloaded OpenCV 3.4.0 and I have successfully imported cv2 (imread, im.show, ... are working fine). I have just a problem using Mat: 
Running the simple script

```
import cv2 

Mat E = Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64F);
```

I have a syntax error using Mat.
Someone can help me??

Comment: You are mixing python and c++ code. In python you use numpy arrays for the Mat variables in OpenCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing c++ instructions with python.

In python `cv::Mat` objects are represented with numpy arrays, and you may use numpy arrays functions to generate them:

The equivalent of :

```
Mat E = Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64F);
```

in python will be:

```
import numpy as np
E = np.eye(4, dtype=np.float64)
```

E will be:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Ok!! Thank you very much...This sound like a really beginner error!

Comment: @Zio_Fe No problem, if this answers your question, don't forget to accept it, this way it may help others to find the correct answer :)